# List item click doesn't trigger when new list items created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what I'm missing here.

My code works fine when there are no new items.

[Sample of items](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltb3sxvr/8/)

But when I edit my list the click won't trigger anymore.

[Sample of edited items](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltb3sxvr/7/)

This is the code that triggers:

```
$('.coupon_options ul li').on('click', function(){
  $selectPromo.removeClass('is_show');
  $couponOptionsBox.addClass('active');

  $(this).parent().find('li a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('selected');

  var selected = $(this).data('code');
  $couponOptionsBox.html(selected);
});
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please add the html code as well.

Comment: what do you mean 'when i edit' as in via the script at some later point?

Comment: last fiddle provides error `$body is not defined`

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Aint it enough that the HTML is in the fiddles?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan html code found in jsfiddle links.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `$body` is not used in this example. but `$body` is `var $body = $('body');`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Fiddle is an external link, don't you think since the question is in StackOverflow and important details related to the question should be in this thread instead of some external location?

Comment: @just_a_simple_guy If you open both fiddles you can see $body is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements.

```
$('.coupon_options ul').on('click','li', function() {
  $selectPromo.removeClass('is_show');
  $couponOptionsBox.addClass('active');

  $(this).parent().find('li a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('selected');

  var selected = $(this).data('code');
  $couponOptionsBox.html(selected);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/Ltb3sxvr/9/)

Answer (score 1):

you are binding the click event handler to `$('.coupon_options ul li')` which are not present at that moment. (but later are added on interaction), you have to add the ventlistener, later (on markup update), or delegate the event similar to what you do with $body and click

Answer (score 0):

Put `$selectPromo.html()` before click function and it works

```js
var $selectPromo = $('.coupon_options ul');
var $couponOptionsBox = $('.coupon_options_box');
$selectPromo.html('<li data-code="7073be"><a href="javascript:" class="great-bumper-stickers-sale-2017"><div class="coupon_name">Great Bumper Stickers Sale</div><div class="coupon_desc">Get your free 20% discount coupon valid bumper stickers orders above $100</div><div class="coupon_code">Promo Code: 7073be</div></a></li><li data-code="17fb5b"><a href="javascript:" class="gift-voucher-10-2017"><div class="coupon_name">Gift Voucher $10</div><div class="coupon_desc">Get a $10 discount on your purchase.</div><div class="coupon_code">Promo Code: 17fb5b</div></a></li>');

$couponOptionsBox.on('click', function() {
  $couponOptionsBox.addClass('active');
  $selectPromo.toggleClass('is_show');

  
});

$('.coupon_options ul li').on('click', function() {
  $selectPromo.removeClass('is_show');
  $couponOptionsBox.addClass('active');

  $(this).parent().find('li a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('selected');

  var selected = $(this).data('code');
  $couponOptionsBox.html(selected);
});

$body.on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.coupon_options_box').length === 0) {
    $selectPromo.removeClass('is_show');
    $couponOptionsBox.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.singaprinting.com/layout-test/ozstickerprinting/css/custom.css">

<div class="order_checkout_promocode">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Coupon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p class="promo-discount">-$8.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="coupon_options">
      <span class="coupon_options_box">Select Coupon</span>
      <ul>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no. i need the `$selectPromo.html()` inside click because i am going to dynamically change the contents. but thank you. i got my answer already